# JavaScript Object and Properties

Tags: javascript, object

Is it possible to reuse a property during the declaration in JavaScript?

Example : `phone_min: breakpoint.small_max + 1,`

**Code**

```
var breakpoint = {
  small_max: 479,
  phone_min: breakpoint.small_max + 1,
};
```

I got error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'small_max' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot do that. In an object initializer, it's not possible to refer to the object that is "under construction".

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible in JavaScript. You can save `small_max` in variable and then use it:

```
var small_max = 479;
var breakpoint = {
  small_max: small_max,
  phone_min: small_max + 1,
};
```